# Hiding content/scroll bar while using loading overlay?

Tags: jquery, html, css

My site is using a loading overlay while it's loading in the background. However, the scroll bar still shows up which means the visitor can go to wherever and if the site finishes loading, the visitor won't see the site from the top. So, I'd like to hide it and not allow the visitor to scroll.

[image]

Here's my code:

CSS:

```
#load {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 5000;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 25%;
}
```

HTML/jQuery:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div id="load">
      Loading...
    </div>    
    <script>
      jQuery(window).load(function(){
        jQuery('#load').fadeOut();
      });
    </script>
    <div class= ...
  </body>
</html>
```

`<div class= ...` means the beginning of the real content of the site.

Comment: Even if you put `html, body{height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden}` while loading, it won't stop some mobile browsers, they will still allow scrolling. Maybe to put the container inside the invisible div, than show it when loading is complete.

Comment: Try setting `display:none` for the content and set it to `display:block` when loaded (within the load function).

Comment: You can scroll back to top before fading out the loader.

Comment: @NawedKhan Yes, but I don't want the visitor to scroll back, I want him to start it from the top.

Comment: what I meant was scroll back the screen to top "dynamically" using JQuery right before the code that fades back the loader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/rfaa3hcr/

```js
$('body').css({
  overflow: 'hidden'
});
setTimeout(function(){
  $('#load').fadeOut('slow', function(){
    $('body').css({
      overflow: 'auto'
    });
  });
}, 5000);
```

```css
#load {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 5000;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top:25%;
}

body{
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="load">
    Loading...
</div>
```

> **CSS** changes:
>   `height: 100vh` instead of `100%` and added `overflow: hidden;`
>   Body with 1000px to showcase your problem.
>
> **JavaScript** changes:
>   Initially `overflow:hidden` set to body using `jQuery`. Used `setTimeout` to showcase the fixed of problem & then after **5sec** `fadeout` the load & show `overflow` as `auto`.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Welcome buddy :)

Comment: @Shiladitya Hi I'm using canvas this code is not working what might be the issue?